# undefined value in a list

Tags: javascript, ajax, undefined

I'm a beginner in Ajax but a have a problem that I can't solved.

I'm trying to get the variable "label" in my list to compare it.
i keep getting this error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined
>   URL : http://localhost:8098/g2s/main/groupama/entreesParDomaine/entreesParDomaine.js?bust=1550141236956

Here is the comparison i'm trying to do :

JS File :

```
for (var k = 0; k < ucManager.listComponent.length; k++) {
    var nbEntreesReel = 0;
    //Boucle sur les issues de jira
    for (var j = 0; j < nbIssue; j++) {
        var listDomainIssue = ucManager.listIssue[j].domainList;
        var comptabilise = false;
        var no = true;
        var listLabelIssue = ucManager.listIssue[j].labelList;
        for (var l = 0; l < listDomainIssue.length; l++) {
           if (listDomainIssue[l].name == ucManager.listComponent[k].text) {
             comptabilise = true;
           }
        }
        for (var test = 0; listLabelIssue.length; test++) {
            if (listLabelIssue[test].label == "TGC1") {
               no = false;
            }
        }
}
```

The list : listIssue has 3 element inside : id, label and issuenum.
So i'm trying to do the exact same loop that the `listDomainIssue[l].name == ucManager.listComponent[k].text`

But it doesn't work.

Hre is the Ajax part but I don't really know how to properly used it.

AJAx :

```
initJiraData : function() {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : REST_PATH + 'groupama/jira/jiraDataGc',
            dataType : "json",
            async : false,
            contentType : 'application/json',
            success : function(data) {
                ucManager.listIssue = data.listIssue;
                var nbComponent = data.listComponent.length;
                for (i = 0; i < nbComponent; i++) {
                    var temp = new Object();
                    temp.id = i;
                    temp.text = data.listComponent[i].name;
                    ucManager.listComponent[i] = temp;
```

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Have you tried going `console.log(listLabelIssue[test]` before trying to access the `label` property to make sure it exists?

Comment: it exist here is what i get when i debug the listLabelIssue :                                
      0:
id: 12068
issuenum: 482
label: "TGC1"
__proto__: Object
1:
id: 12069
issuenum: 482
label: "Urgence"
__proto__: Object

Comment: Does it breaks in first comparison itself ?

Comment: Aah, are you doing that loop inside the `success` function of your `ajax` call? The console logs change if the data is loaded later, so it's possible the function runs first, then the ajax is finishing and getting the data later -> check timings ;)

Answer (score 0):

On the fourth loop you have missed the `<`.

It should be

```
for (var test = 0; test < listLabelIssue.length; test++) {
        if (listLabelIssue[test].label == "TGC1") {
           no = false;
        }
    }
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

somehow you used wrong syntax for loop
please correct the loop for (var test = 0;**test< l**istLabelIssue.length; test++)

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing the following line:

```
for (var test = 0; listLabelIssue.length; test++) {
```

with:

```
for (var test = 0; test < listLabelIssue.length; test++) {
```

the condition with listLabelIssue.length will always get true, if array is not empty. And also creates infinite loop.